# Network byte order to host byte order conversion Java

Tags: java, jna

I am using a windows-dll through jna for communicating with some dongle servers. The dll provides three functions, which are connect, disconnect and getting the connection status of the dongles. Connecting and disconnecting works. But when I query the status, the device should return an ip-address which i save into a DWORD. The code is something like, where `DWORDByReference IpAddress` is an out-parameter:

`int AwUsbGetConnectionStatus(String Hub, DWORDByReference IpAddress, IntByReference Status, DWORD Timeout, HANDLE Event);
DWORD value = ipAddress.getValue();`

The specification of the dll states: "IpAddress is in host byte order and can be converted to TCP/IP network byte order using the WinSock htonl function."

In another thread i read that the java equivalent to htonl is:

`static int htonl(int val) {
  return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(val)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).getInt(0);
}`

But the problem is, that i get weird values. But somehow they do correspond to the supposed value of the ip-addresses.
For example when the original Ip was: 192.168.102.118 
it returns 1986439360 
and when i convert it with the method above, it's -1062705546.
But i guess it should be 192168102118 when converted properly

Also another Ip-Address i tried was:
192.168.102.112
for which i get 1885776064
and when i convert that it's -106270552

So the difference between the Ip-Addresses is still 6 for the original Address and for the converted value. I tried this with different Ips and the difference between the Ips always matches the supposed values.
So does anyone know, if there is something wrong with the way i convert the value the dll-function returns or could there even be a problem when i get the value of the DWORD parameter?

Comment: `192168102118` is too big for a 32-bit value. It doesn't concatenate the string values of each of the numbers. A quick sanity check; If you have more than 10 digits, its not an `int`.

Comment: Note: `Integer.reverseBytes(x)` is much faster/simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the order *before* putting the little-endian address into it.

And it appears (from your comment "i guess it should be 192168102118 when converted properly") that you want dotted-quad output; for that, using a byte array may be more natural:

```
static byte[] htoip(int ipv4) {
  return ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[4])
                   .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                   .putInt(ipv4)
                   .array();
}
```

This result is suitable for passing to [`InetAddress.getByAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByAddress-byte:A-), etc.

While this isn't the simplest way to reverse 4 bytes, its use of `ByteOrder.nativeOrder()` makes it portable and future-proof.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break your decimal value (-1062705546) out into the 4 bytes that make it up. If you do so, you would get, in hexadecimal notation:

C0 A8 66 76

Which corresponds to 192.168.102.118.

Answer (score 1):

The values returned by the method are correct.
In Java all integers are signed. It does not have unsigned types.

For your IP 192.168.102.118 the HEX number is C0 A8 66 76 which converted to a signed integer is -1062705546